# How to access parent class object through derived class instance?

Tags: python

Let's suppose I have these classes:

```
class A():
    msg = 'hehehe'

class B(A):
    msg = 'hohoho'

class C(B):
    pass
```

and an instance of `B` or `C`. How do I get the variable `msg` from the parent's class object through this instance?

I've tried this:

```
foo = B()
print super(foo.__class__).msg
```

but got the message:

> TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the class is single-inherited:

```
foo = B()
print foo.__class__.__bases__[0].msg
# 'hehehe'
```

If the class is multiple-inherited, the question makes no sense because there may be multiple classes defining the 'msg', and they could all be meaningful. You'd better provide the actual parent (i.e. `A.msg`). Alternatively you could iterate through all direct bases as described in [@Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265097/)'s answer.

Comment: And what if the class inherits from multiple classes? Your approach will probably work most of the time, but it is not reliable.

Comment: May work in simple cases but not recommended. Use the 2 argument version of super() as shown by Tim Dumol.

Comment: The `__class__.__mro__` attribute mentioned below provides all the bases so should work for multiple inheritance. It also doesn't require the base class(es) to inherit from `object` to get them which is a bad limitation of `super`.

Answer (score 16):

You actually want to use

```
class A(object):
    ...
...
foo = B()
bar = super(foo.__class__, foo)
print bar.msg
```

Base classes must be new-style classes (inherit from `object`)

Comment: The trouble with this answer is that the base class must inherit from `object` which it may not. It would be useful if `super` provided a way to access the base class itself and it's attributes like `__class__.__bases__` provides.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you want to do this

```
>>> class A(object):
...     msg = 'hehehe'
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     msg = 'hohoho'
... 
>>> foo=B()
>>> foo.__class__.__mro__[1].msg
'hehehe'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
class A(object):
    msg = 'hehehe'
```

EDIT:

For the 'msg' attribute you would need:

```
foo = B()
bar = super(foo.__class__, foo)
print bar.msg
```

Comment: No it does not work. He would get following error: `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'msg'`.

Comment: Well, i was focusing on the error he mentions: "TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj" which disappears if he uses classes derived from "object". It is a good piece of advice anyway to use those new style classes! I edited my answer to include the "msg" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

As `msg` is a class variable, you can just do:

```
print C.msg    # prints hohoho
```

If you overwrite the variable (as you do in class `B`), you have to find the right parent class. Remember that Python supports **multiple inheritance**.

But as you define the classes and you now that `B` inherits from `A` you can always do this:

```
class B(A):
    msg = 'hohoho'

    def get_parent_message(self):
       return A.msg
```

**UPDATE:**

The most reliable thing would be:

```
def get_parent_attribute(instance, attribute):
    for parent in instance.__class__.__bases__:
        if attribute in parent.__dict__:
             return parent.__dict__[attribute]
```

and then:

```
foo = B()
print get_parent_attribute(foo, 'msg')
```

Comment: yes, I know. But what if i don't know what exactly parent class of given instance is, and I need to access exactly its 'msg'?

Comment: @PyNewbie: If you don't know the parent class, how do you know that it has a `msg` attribute?

Comment: @PyNewbie: look at my answer: you did it right, but you forgot to use the "new" object class of python; all your classes should inherit from "object" and you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

```
#for B() you can use __bases__
print foo.__class__.__bases__[0].msg
```

But this is not gonna be easy when there are multiple base classes and/or the depth of hierarchy is not one.