# How to access parent class object reference through child class instance?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 20
        Parent.__init__(self)

child_obj = Child()
```

I tried following:

```
parent_ref_of_child_obj = super(child_obj.__class__, b)
```

Basically I tried all the answers of [Python: How to access parent class object through derived class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265060/python-how-to-access-parent-class-object-through-derived-class-instance).

Comment: `child_obj.__class__.__mro__[1]`

Comment: `type(child_obj).mro()[1]`

Comment: If you're interested in only the child class' immediate parent, you can use the `__base__` attribute` of the child class: `type(child_obj).__base__`